# How to get data out of $_POST after it was sent with $.ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

I'm sending data with ajax:

```
$('article.work a').click(function(e){
    var h = $(this).attr('href');

    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: h,
      data: workItems,
      success: function(data){
        console.log('success');
        window.location = h;
      },
      error: function(){
        console.log('eror');                    
      }             
    });
});
```

it sends ok and after checking in firebug post tab it looks like:

[image: Post value]

So i believe it is sending correct data. But when I try to retrieve it from $_POST via php and I do

```
<?php 
print_r(json_decode($_POST["json"])); 
?>;
```

nothing is printed.

What am I doing wrong? 
Why won't $_POST recognize my data even though it is sent?

Comment: Did you try `<?php var_dump($_POST); ?>` ?

Comment: @Marin Sagovac Yes I did try - the value returned is `array(0) { } `

Comment: Try: `var_dump($_POST['json'], true)`. This means that will result as associative array, rather than object.

Comment: And please, go to `Header` tab on Chrome and see what is method, post/get?

Comment: You are aware that you're redirecting to the same page in the success callback  ?

Comment: @adeneo not sure about that - I have a link to an item on a listing and I get on the detail page and all shows up except my $_POST data.

Comment: I think is encoding problem. Look at my answers, but not sure.

Comment: But I'm sure, inside the success handler you have `document.location = h;` and that's a redirect.

Comment: @adeneo Updated my complete click code.

Comment: Comment this code `//window.location = h;`

Comment: @Marin Sagovac Ohhh, that did it - but how can I rewrite the url after the call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

`var_dump($_POST['json'], true)`. This means that will result as associative array, rather than object.

Try:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "h",
        type: "post",
        data: workItems,
    });
```

And try get a data using `var_dump($_POST);` or as associative array: `var_dump($_POST['workItems'], true);`.

I think before outputing a result of JSON should be correctly formatted as UTF8:

```
$result = mb_convert_encoding($result,'UTF-8','UTF-8'); 
$result = json_decode($result);
```

Put above code before outputs a JSON code.

Comment: Tried the above code and `var_dump($_POST['workItems'], true)` returns `NULL bool(true)`

Comment: Did you putted header on a file `header("Content-Type: application/json", true);` before output of POST?

Comment: as stated in comments the problem was me doing the redirect. It works now - thanks for pointing that out - really missed that bit in js.